# set of firebase users permission android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my app I have a menu in my action bar. I need to make that 
when a set of users is logged in the first, the menu will appear. 
When the second set of users logs in, the second menu will appear. 
So this is a beginning I have tried that for one users that I know its id like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the main_menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    currentuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();
    if (currentuser.equals("b3C28u0hX3WAIEPvtLnCMcUoUMn1")) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu2, menu);
    } else {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu);
    }
    return true;
}
```

know i need it for a dynamic set of users not just one

Comment: from where is the dynamic set of users? local or on the db?

Comment: firebase realtime database

Comment: Please  share your structure and code you are using to retrieve the data

Comment: And what happend? Do you have an error? If not, which one of the menus is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You should define properties in your users model that say if it belongs to set1 or set2.
Most probably, the basic Firebase auth is not enough, so you may have to define a FB realtime database, in which you have a user node, and users inside, matching the id of Firebase Authenticator, and which contains that supplementary information.

It's quite a bit more work to add support for the realtime DB, however this has proven to work well in one of my app.

Comment: its already added the 2 sets in my DB with email and auth id and i have tried to retrieve this data within ondatachange method and make it in arraylist but because of its scope give me empty array outside the method